# Traceroute - Header Link CURL result Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, tcp, curl, traceroute, port-443

We have systematic CURLs run every 15 mins - 2 hours from this system and logging their status. Every other CURL for the past 2 months has succeeded except this. Is there a way to identify why this one failed?

This was a CURL result to my domain. This TCP-based traceroute was generated immediately following an error condition that we've recently detected.

Site/Device: Header Link - (Secure Web Server)
IP Address: 51.171.182.89
Traceroute from: Sao Paulo, Brazil
Traceroute started on 2022-01-25 at 09:34:12 (GMT 0).

```
--- Traceroute ---

NOTE: This TCP traceroute was long-running     
      and may contain partial results. 

Selected device eth0, address 172.30.2.133, port 58873 for outgoing packets     
Tracing the path to 51.171.182.89 on TCP port 443 (https), 30 hops max 
 1  * * *       
 2  245.251.22.246  0.233 ms  0.230 ms  0.227 ms       
 3  230.0.74.24  0.252 ms  0.235 ms  0.216 ms   
 4  241.1.58.1  3.943 ms  0.714 ms  0.572 ms   
 5  175.72.240.118  9.957 ms  4.656 ms  3.704 ms       
 6  51.91.44.104  5.792 ms  28.701 ms  4.403 ms
 7  51.91.44.104 14.315 ms  3.833 ms  4.052 ms
 8  100.91.202.0  117.641 ms  117.927 ms  118.044 ms   
 9  150.222.230.20  117.598 ms  117.319 ms  118.042 ms 
10  100.91.198.47  117.974 ms  118.045 ms  117.381 ms   
11  100.91.198.68  117.418 ms  117.522 ms  117.761 ms   
12  100.91.160.67  117.509 ms  117.365 ms  117.994 ms   
13  100.91.160.52  118.137 ms  121.071 ms  120.095 ms   
14  100.91.177.51  117.339 ms  117.060 ms  117.210 ms   
15  100.100.8.10  117.478 ms  117.408 ms  126.012 ms   
16  100.100.82.200  117.493 ms  118.551 ms  117.511 ms 
17  100.100.82.207  117.514 ms  159.002 ms  165.942 ms 
18  100.100.14.104  117.407 ms  122.265 ms  128.128 ms 
19  100.100.24.60  117.321 ms  117.416 ms  117.077 ms   
20  51.93.30.58  126.877 ms  123.185 ms  117.461 ms     
21  * * *       
22  * * *       
23  * * *       
24  * * *       
25  *
```

Could anyone advise how we can look into the cause of this issue further? what might be the cause of the issue?

Comment: The output of curl would be helpful.

Comment: Please also add tcptraceroute for a healthy connection. Most likely this is random internet connectivity breakage, which happens all the time.

Comment: The internet is not a guaranteed service. Only one failure in months is pretty good.

Comment: Is there any scope to find out the actual region behind it??